# objective c renderInContext crash on background thread

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cgcontext, screen-capture, mainwindow

I have an app in which the screen continuously is capturing in background thread. Here is the code

```
- (UIImage *) captureScreen {

    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[keyWindow layer] renderInContext:context];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        img=[self rotatedImage:img];
    }
    return img;
}
```

It works good for capturing once or twice. But after a while the app crashes always on the same line `[[keyWindow layer] renderInContext:context];` and it gives `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)` message. I searched everywhere and nothing useful. Found only that renderInContext has memory leak issue when it works in background thread. But as you understand that doesn't solve my issue :) . 
So have 3 questions :-

1. What is the reason of this crash (problem)?
2. What can I do with this?
3. Is there any other way to capture screen (beside the one that Apple suggests, because there renderInContext is also used). Something without rendering...?

Comment: you should perform your GUI related tasks on main thread

Comment: show us your rendering code. are you attempting to use core data objects in a thread that they were not created on. are you using non-atomic properties in your rendering code. both of these and more could cause this.

Comment: Is any of `layer` or `context` nil when calling `renderInContext`? Is the `receivedMemoryWarning` method being called?

Comment: @WarrenBurton I'm writing kind of a library so my code cannot be based on main thread only. I have two other threads one for capturing another for sending the image. So yes maybe I'm using core data objects created in main thread. Also can you explain why non-atomic property is so important here???

Comment: @ott-- I'm not sure about layer and context cz haven't checked...But in some cases when crash happens I get "Recieved Memory Warning" message and in some cases I don't. Trying still... :(

Comment: actually Fabiens answer is correct , if your rendering code was duff for threading  it would show up in the stack trace. You most likely have to create  a fresh context for the thread rather than trying to re-use the one from another thread.

Comment: but in code above I use context that is created in the same method, which means it is in the same thread...what is the problem here?

Comment: also I would like to mention that crash almost always happens on websites which has semi-transparent overlay. (My App has webview in which I can load different websites to test app).

Comment: HI,Have you found a solution for this,im also having same problem?If so pls share the solution

Answer (score 8):

`-renderInContext:` is not thread-safe and you can't call it from a background thread. You'll have to do the drawing on the main thread.

Comment: But if I do cyclic capturing in main thread, the UI will stuck, right? This way it works, but crashes, and may be the reason is that it is not thread safe... :( ???

Comment: This is right, you're UI will lock while you are rendering the screenshots. Means you'll have to find a user friendly way to make this happen, throwing up a HUD or something similar.

Comment: I have the same issue, on background thread renderincontext crashes some times. Can you expand on the HUD comment?

Comment: @Gamma-Point By HUD he meant that you can use a sort of a loader and prevent users interaction with the view. Here is the link to a good implementation of the HUD Component https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 3):

I had nothing to do but performing this method on main thread. I reorganized my  thread management and could get good result for me doing this:

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(captureScreenOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone: YES];` Last parameter can be set to no in some cases...

Thanks for all responses.